# sbt lagom template+InvalidRemoteException

Tags: sbt, lagom

I tried to follow the follow tutorial:

https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/GettingStartedSbt.html

For generating the project scaffolding, I want to use the following template:

```
sbt new lagom/lagom-java.g8
```

But already receive the following error:

```
[error] org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: origin
```

A bit frustrating at such early stage in the tutorial... 
Any idea how to fix this?

Edit: the error is caused by:

```
[error] Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: https//github.com/lagom/lagom-java.g8.git: not found.
```

Seems there is a `:`missing after https. How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Verify you have the prerequisites.  Prerequisites documented here https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/JavaPrereqs.html

I just followed the instructions and was unable to reproduce the error from the CLI using sbt version 1.1.1.

What version of sbt are you using?

Comment: My prerequisites are fine. Sbt version is 1.1.14. I'm currently creating the setup manually, good lessons anyway.